# page transitions using javascript

Tags: javascript

i saw this on a site a couple of days ago and i cant seem to find it again.

in any case, this is what was on the site:

the page opened regularly when you entered the url. upon clicking one of the links on the page, it "transitioned" to the next page (there was a color change). and the url in the address bar was changed to reflect that. eg: if the background was blue on site.com, when clicking on the about link, the background would change to green and the browser would show site.com/about. and so on.

also, if the url entered was site.com/about, the bg would be green and on cliking the home page, the site would transition from green to blue and browser would show site.com

im interested in finding out how this was done. searching on google got me the meta-refresh tag, but the ffect was much more complex and worked on all browsers.

is there any other method out there?

Comment: Dare I suggest that it's probably a bad idea? Even **if** you're doing some kind of slideshow/PowerPoint imitating website. Just let the visitor move around without JS transitions. Please?

Comment: its for the aesthetics of it. im not really concerned about usability/seo-friendlienss(gasp!)/regular concerns. 


im more interested in learning HOW it was done.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of realizations. The simplest way is [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can find page transition generator right here :

- http://www.designerwiz.com/mf.htm?http&&&www.designerwiz.com/generator/dhtml_page_effect_generator.htm

if you wanna do it via jQuery, here is a tutorial about it :

- http://weston.ruter.net/projects/jquery-css-transitions/

and sample :

- http://weston.ruter.net/projects/jquery-css-transitions/code/example.html

Comment: like ive mentioned, ive gone through the meta-tags way of doing it and thats not exactly what i was looking for. 
as far as the jquery method is concerned, it seems to deal only with divs transitioning. not the entire page. also, it wont work on ie6 and my goal is to be browser compliant as far as possible and ie6 is still used widely.
thanks a lot tho.

Comment: Put your whole content into a main div. Then use jQueries transition effect. That is all easy.